# NodeJS - error npm undefined symbol uv_fs_realpath

Tags: shell, arch-linux, node.js, npm

i'm trying to install yo (linux) using npm

```
npm install -g yo
```

but i get this error :

```
node: symbol lookup error: node: undefined symbol: uv_fs_realpath
```

when i only type npm, it return same error message (see above).

Comment: Your nodejs installation is broken, how did you install it?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Problem solved, i just reinstall node, no more error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reinstall node

```
sudo pacman -Rdd nodejs
```

then

```
sudo pacman -S nodejs
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by an outdated libuv.

Upgrading libuv via <del>`pacman -Sy libuv`</del> fixed this issue for me. No reinstall needed.

EDIT: You should upgrade your system first, then libuv:

```
pacman -Syu libuv
```

Comment: @jasonwryan, fixed.